# Install pyserial Mac OS 10.10?

Tags: python, pyserial

Attempting to communicate with Arduino serial ports using Python 2.7. Have downloaded pyserial 2.7 (unzipped and put folder pyserial folder in python application folder). Didn't work error message. "No module named pyserial".

Confused about how to install from terminal. Any assistance greatly appreciated.

http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Developer-Tools/pySerial.shtml

Comment: IIRC, the easiest way is to run `python setup.py install` from the pyserial directory once you've unzipped it. But, take a look at [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) or [easy_install](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html), which are both much simpler in the long run than the "easy way."

Comment: If I remembered how to use Python, I would have made it an answer. Why not answer your own question with the steps you used (and mark it as the answer) so that others can benefit from what you learned. (You'll have to wait a few hours before SO will let you answer your own question, however.)

Answer (score 6):

try install with :

```
sudo pip install pyserial
```

Answer (score 1):

This was helpful for me:
http://www.maclife.com/article/feature/25_terminal_tips_every_mac_user_should_know

Specifically:

> For commands that require the path to a file or folder, save yourself some typing by dragging and dropping the file or folder at the end of the command. The Terminal will automatically copy the dropped item’s path and name.

So I clicked and dragged my pyserial fodler into terminal, hit enter, terminal said that it was a directory, then i typed "sudo install pyserial" and typed my password in and hit enter.

This was helpful when I couldn't figure out how to enter my password:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214900

Comment: TY for that drag and drop comment

Comment: did you mean "sudo *pip* install pyserial" ?